# How to use RSSetScissorRects with multiple rects?

Tags: directx11

I try this and work only first rect.

```
D3D11_RECT rc[2];
rc[0] = {0, 0, 16, 16};
rc[1] = {32, 32, 64, 64};

m_d3d11DevCon->RSSetScissorRects( 2, rc );
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476478(v=vs.85).aspx

> Which scissor rectangle to use is determined by the SV_ViewportArrayIndex semantic output by a geometry shader (see shader semantic syntax). If a geometry shader does not make use of the SV_ViewportArrayIndex semantic then Direct3D will use the first scissor rectangle in the array.
>
> Each scissor rectangle in the array corresponds to a viewport in an array of viewports (see [ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476480(v=vs.85).aspx)).

The conditions for being able to use multiple scissor rectangles are therefore:

- You must also be using an array of viewports.
- Each scissor rect needs a corresponding viewport.
- the geometry shader stage must be active.
- The geometry shader must write to SV_ViewportArrayIndex which determines both the viewport and scissor rect to use.

Otherwise the behaviour is that only the first scissor rect is used.

Comment: The quote is a little misleading, but the next one on that MSDN page is most relevant: "Each scissor rectangle in the array corresponds to a viewport in an array of viewports (see ``ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports``)."